# how to configure cypal plugins into eclipse

Tags: java, gwt, collections

I am trying to configure the eclipse with the cypal studio  to run GWT (Google Web Toolkit) into java application. now i am trying to find libraries for cypal to configure into eclipse but i am not able to find the proper solution for installing plugins in eclipse.

Comment: Please read through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html and if you have a more specific question, ask away.

Comment: here is detailed ans i got ..http://www.java67.com/2017/04/how-to-convert-java-8-stream-to-array-and-list-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using collections framework in Java, a developer has to use loops and make repeated checks. Another concern is efficiency; as multi-core processors are available at ease, a Java developer has to write parallel code processing that can be pretty error-prone.

To resolve such issues, Java 8 introduced the concept of stream that lets the developer to process data declaratively and leverage multicore architecture without the need to write any specific code for it. Using stream, you can process data in a declarative way.

In **Java 8**, Collection interface has two methods to generate a Stream −

**stream()** − Returns a sequential stream considering collection as its source.

**parallelStream()** − Returns a parallel Stream considering collection as its source.

**Example:**

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd","", "jkl");
List<String> filtered = strings.stream().filter(string -> !string.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `filter()` method is used to eliminate elements based on a criteria. Like this there are so many methods in **Stream**.

You can also check this link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

here i got difference.
Collection is a data structure. Based on the problem you decide which collection to be used like ArrayList, LinekedList (Considering time and space complexity) . Where as Stream is just a processing kind of tool, which makes your life easy.
Other difference is, you can consider Collection as in-memory data structure, where you can add , remove element. Where as in Stream you can perform two kind of operation:

a. Intermediate operation : Filter, map ,sort,limit on the result set
b. Terminal operation : forEach ,collect the result set to a collection.

But if you notice, with stream you can't add or remove elements.
Stream is kind of iterator, you can traverse collection through stream. Note, you can traverse stream only once, let me give you an example to have better understanding:
Example:

```
List<String> employeeNameList = Arrays.asList("John","Peter","Sachin");
Stream<String> s = employeeNameList.stream();

// iterate through list
s.dorEach(System.out :: println);  // this work's perfectly fine
s.dorEach(System.out :: println);  // you will get IllegalStateException, stating stream already operated upon
```

So, what you can infer is, collection you can iterate as many times as you want. But for the stream, once you iterate , it won't remember what it is supposed to do. So, you need to instruct it again.